# How can i use scan in Ruby to select specific symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scanf

i start code in Ruby, but i want to know if in scan i could selection some operations symbol.

For example:

```
var = ["+100,-20,-15,+30"]
var.scan(/\d+/).map{|i| print i.to_i}
```

and my answer is:

```
0312100100102001010010010010
```

but i need keep ",+-", this si possible with scan?

because my problem is get a finish result in var

Comment: This code does not work right now because `Array#scan` is not a method and the result does not make any sense. Can you please clarify the question?

Comment: Hi!! i have a text like this var = ["+100,-20,-15,+30"] in this case i need get a sum this numbers tot = 95. But in scan i cant do this! var.scan(/\d+/).map{|i| print i.to_i} this comeback this 100201530, right? And how can i do this sum this string? Have a form in scan or other way....

Answer (score 0):

`var` in your question is an array, not a string (the square brackets on each side indicates it is an array). But if you did have a comma-separated string of integers and wanted to add those integers, like your comment suggested, you could do this:

```
var = "+100,-20,-15,+30"
var.split(",").map(&:to_i).sum(0)
# => 95
```